# dynamic reloading of a combobox when hetting a refresh button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Am new to ajax , and i'm having trouble implement a dynamic reloading of a combobox when hetting a refresh button.

```
    <html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    alert('Document is ready');
    $('#b').on('click', function(){

    alert('You clicked the button');
    $('#s').load(test.php);

});

 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="s" id="s">
 <?php       $server = 'localhost'; //localhost is the usual name of the server if apache/Linux.
$login = 'root';
$pword = '';
$dbname = 'item';
mysql_connect($server,$login,$pword) or die($connect_error); //or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die($connect_error);
?>
<?php
    $query = "select * from ajax_categories";
    $results = mysql_query($query);

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(@$results))
    {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>"><?php echo $rows['category'];?></option>
    <?php
    }?>

</select>
<input type = "button" value="go" name="b" id="b">
```

and the test.php code :

```
    <?php
    $query = "select * from ajax_categories";
    $results = mysql_query($query);

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(@$results))
    {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>"><?php echo $rows['category'];?></option>
    <?php
    }?>
```

it shows the alert but the combobox doesnt reloading the new database content

Comment: as a programmer who worked a lot with ajax, I suggest you to use $.ajax instead of $.load

Comment: What is _hetting_?

Answer (score 0):

try changing this :

```
 $('#s').load(test.php);
```

to this :

```
 $('#s').load('test.php');
```

String literals is important.